# Output scores in a text file in ascending order C#

Tags: c#

```
string[] Entry = *File path*
                        var orderedEntries = Entry.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Split(" ")[1]));
                        foreach (var score in orderedEntries)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(Entry);
                        }
```

I have a text file with the following format:
Name Highscore (The name is an inputted string and the highscore is a calculated integer)
What I want to happen is that the program outputs all of the names and high scores, ordered by their scores so the highest score is outputted first. I found this code in an answer to a similar question but when I run it, it outputs "System.String[]" instead of the actual entries.

Apologies if this is a slight duplicate, couldn't find anything that I could use to help me in this situation.

Comment: How do I do the latter then.

Comment: you're trying to print a `string[]`, not its contents.  try looping through `Entry` (with a `foreach` or `for`, doesn't matter either way) and print what it's storing, i.e. do something along the lines of `Console.WriteLine(Entry[i]);` or `Console.WriteLine(entry);` for a `for` and `foreach` loop, respectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see any code to read the contents of the file. I'd try something like

```
string[] entries = File.ReadAllLines("filename.txt");
var orderedEntries = entries.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Split(" ")[1]));
foreach (var entry in orderedEntries)
{
    Console.WriteLine(entry);
}
```

This works if the score is the second word in each line. If it's the first, you need to use `int.Parse(x.Split(" ")[0]`.

Comment: This works, although it writes them in descending order, anyway I can change it so it does ascending.

Comment: Yes, use OrderByDescending to reverse the order

Comment: Perfect thanks, will set as right answer when it lets me!

Comment: Just wondering if there is a way to only print say the first 5 entries, so like a top scores thing.

Comment: You can use the `Take` function like this `foreach (var entry in orderedEntries.Take(5))`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var orderedEntries = Entry.Select(x => new {name = x.Split(' ')[0], highscore = int.Prase(x.Split(' ')[1])}).OrderByDescending(x => x.highscore));
foreach (var entry in orderedEntries)
{
     Console.WriteLine($"name={entry.name} highscore={entry.highscore}");
}
```